# What does "flag weight 120" mean?

Tags: support, flagging, user-accounts

On my profile page the following is written: "flag weight 120"

What does this mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question  because it is about a feature that no longer exists.

Answer (score 13):

You can find all the information you need here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight/80178#80178

Comment: Just an FYI: this link no longer works.

Answer (score 4):

I would think that the idea of "search before asking" would apply to meta as well.  I actually had the exact same question.  (What is flag weight) I searched "flag weight stack exchange" in Google (didn't even search the meta) and the first hit told me everything.